# Can I set the html content in phantomJS?

Tags: node.js

Now I faced a problem, I need to render a html to jpg to show a suitable image on phone.

At first I established a router like "localhost/api/id..." and use this:

```
page.open("localhost/api/id...", function(status) {
  render...
});
```

But now problem seems complex, I want to know is there any api like:

```
page.setHtml(htmlContent, function(status) {
  render...
});
```

I find in document but I can't find it, Maybe because of my English...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `page.setContent(content, location)`

**References:**

[phantomJs Github](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/f69d44b829aaf281441edff7506dde2d5c33ad07/test/module/webpage/set-content.js)

[Documentation (near bottom)](http://phantomjs.org/page-automation.html)